# How to execute curl commands from Node.js

Tags: node.js, xml, curl, command-line, xmlhttprequest

My curl command sends XML data from an XML file, and the response is written to the specified path. How can I make this happen in Node.js?

```
cd C:/test/  && curl  localhost:9001 --data @ C:/test/Basic/SPND.xml -o  C:/test/Basic/Result.xml';
```

Comment: Why do you want to run curl from Node JS? Making HTTP requests is possible using for example the experimental `fetch` or the axios package, node-fetch package, etc. Writing to files is also something you can do using the `fs` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: why console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`) return empty